# yolov7,no mask with the output image

Tags: yolo

i git yolov7(https://github.com/WongKinYiu) with `yolov7.pt` and try to run
`detect.py`(i just want to run the example). it seems to be normal. but the output image has no mask.Why?

here is my code and log:

```
(PyTorch) E:\yolov7>python detect.py --weights yolov7.pt --source inference\images\bus.jpg
Namespace(weights=['yolov7.pt'], source='inference\\images\\bus.jpg', img_size=640, conf_thres=0.25, iou_thres=0.45, device='', view_img=False, save_txt=False, save_conf=False, nosave=False, classes=None, agnostic_nms=False, augment=False, update=False, project='runs/detect', name='exp', exist_ok=False, no_trace=False)
YOLOR  v0.1-103-g6ded32c torch 1.11.0 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, 4095.6875MB)

Fusing layers...
RepConv.fuse_repvgg_block
RepConv.fuse_repvgg_block
RepConv.fuse_repvgg_block
Model Summary: 306 layers, 36905341 parameters, 6652669 gradients
 Convert model to Traced-model...
 traced_script_module saved!
 model is traced!

E:\anaconda\envs\PyTorch\lib\site-packages\torch\functional.py:568: UserWarning: torch.meshgrid: in an upcoming release, it will be required to pass the indexing argument. (Triggered internally at  C:\cb\pytorch_1000000000000\work\aten\src\ATen\native\TensorShape.cpp:2228.)
  return _VF.meshgrid(tensors, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
Done. (151.6ms) Inference, (9.3ms) NMS
 The image with the result is saved in: runs\detect\exp4\bus.jpg
Done. (3.713s)
```

and here is my result:[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrM6E.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You set the argument `classes=None`.
The `classes` variable refers to a list of classes, where you define the index of the entities saved inside the weights you are referencing for the inference.
From `detect.py`:

```
parser.add_argument('--classes', nargs='+', type=int, help='filter by class: --class 0, or --class 0 2 3')
```

Since you told the model to check for zero classes, the model itself will not report anything.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue. After downgrading cuda version to 10.2 my problem was solved. I used Cuda 10.2 with PyTorch 1.10.0 via pip installation. I hope it helps you too.

`pip3 install torch==1.10.0+cu102 torchvision==0.11.1+cu102 torchaudio===0.10.0+cu102 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu102/torch_stable.html`

Answer (score 0):

Source of the answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74696085/yolo-v7-not-detecting-objects-on-image)

Since when you are working with `GPU`, It allows half precision by default, which you can change by editing your `detect.py` file.

Go to `detect.py` file and  not exactly sure but on `line 31`, you will see this line of code:

```
half = device.type != 'cpu'  # half precision only supported on CUDA
```

Replace that line with

```
half = False
```

and then save `default.py` file.

---

Now when you are using your detection command, make sure to use `--device 0` that indicates your GPU must be utilize for detection.

```
python detect.py --weights yolov7.pt --device 0 --source inference\images\bus.jpg
```