# Yolo v7 not detecting objects on image

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection, yolo

I'm trying Yolo v7, it seems to be working, but the resulted image has no object detection mapping on it, while it should have.

I read the Github to how to setup Yolo v7 on Docker, here's the full commands you should be able to reproduce my problem.

```
git clone https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7
cd yolov7

nvidia-docker run --name yolov7 -it --rm -v "$CWD":/yolov7 --shm-size=64g nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:21.08-py3

// on the container
cd /yolov7
python -m pip install virtualenv
python -m virtualenv venv3
. venv3/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
apt update
apt install -y zip htop screen libgl1-mesa-glx
pip install seaborn thop
python detect.py --weights yolov7.pt --conf 0.25 --img-size 640 --source inference/images/horses.jpg
```

And this is the console output of the last command:

```
# python detect.py --weights yolov7.pt --conf 0.25 --img-size 640 --source inference/images/horses.jpg 
Namespace(agnostic_nms=False, augment=False, classes=None, conf_thres=0.25, device='', exist_ok=False, img_size=640, iou_thres=0.45, name='exp', no_trace=False, nosave=False, project='runs/detect', save_conf=False, save_txt=False, source='inference/images/horses.jpg', update=False, view_img=False, weights=['yolov7.pt'])
YOLOR  v0.1-115-g072f76c torch 1.13.0+cu117 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, 3903.875MB)

Fusing layers... 
RepConv.fuse_repvgg_block
RepConv.fuse_repvgg_block
RepConv.fuse_repvgg_block
Model Summary: 306 layers, 36905341 parameters, 6652669 gradients
 Convert model to Traced-model... 
 traced_script_module saved! 
 model is traced! 

/yolov7/venv3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/functional.py:504: UserWarning: torch.meshgrid: in an upcoming release, it will be required to pass the indexing argument. (Triggered internally at ../aten/src/ATen/native/TensorShape.cpp:3190.)
  return _VF.meshgrid(tensors, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
Done. (150.9ms) Inference, (0.3ms) NMS
 The image with the result is saved in: runs/detect/exp6/horses.jpg
Done. (0.616s)
```

Now, I should be able to see the detections on the generated image `runs/detect/exp6/horses.jpg`, from the original image `inference/images/horses.jpg`, right? But I see the two images the same, no difference. What's wrong with the setup?

Nvidia driver:

```
$ nvidia-smi 
Tue Dec  6 09:47:03 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.60.11    Driver Version: 525.60.11    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 45%   27C    P8    N/A /  75W |     13MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1152      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  9MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1256      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                2MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Ubuntu version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Comment: I opened a Github issue: https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/issues/1215

Comment: I see three other people so far have the same problem. Perhaps this is a bug. Let me know a hint or workaround on the problem if you have any here or on the issue page.

Comment: I have the same issue but no idea how to start debugging

Answer (score 2):

When we are using the Gpu . The program allows only to use half precision of the Model . This is what is written in Line 31 of detect.py(# half precision only supported on CUDA).

By changing it to False :
Line 31 : half = False
Does the magic for me .

Answer (score 1):

modify variable half on detect.py file to False

Line 31 :     half = False

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue too. It is basically what others mentioned. Some explanation is added below.

The reason is in line 31 `half = device.type != 'cpu'  # half precision only supported on CUDA`.

Not all GPUs nor all Nvidia GPUs with CUDA support half-precision (16 bit) floats, esp if your GPU is a bit older. In my case, I was using an AMD 5700XT (via ROCM) - this GPU also has no fp16 support!

To make it configurable, I added a command line argument which let the user to override the variable `half` mentioned in other answers;

```py
# After Line 31~, check if command line override is present.
# device = select_device(opt.device)
half = opt.fp16 and device.type != 'cpu'  # half precision only supported on CUDA

# After line (169~) with `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()`
parser.add_argument("--fp16", type=bool, default=False, help="Use float16 (Some GPUs only)")
```